# f# async cancel not working - stuck on console.readline

Tags: asynchronous, f#, cancellation

I am running a simple chat app with f#. In the chat when one user types "exit" then I want both clients to finish the chat. Currently I am running in the console, and so read and write are blocking, but I am using a class to wrap the console so there is no async problems.

(In the following code the sendUI and reciveUI are async functions that send and recieve messages over the wire)

```
type IConnection =
    abstract Send : string -> Async<bool>
    abstract Recieve : unit -> Async<string>
    abstract Connected : bool
    abstract Close : unit -> unit

type IOutput =
    abstract ClearLine : unit -> unit
    abstract ReadLine : ?erase:bool -> string
    abstract WriteLine : string -> unit

let sendUI (outputer:#IOutput) (tcpConn: #IConnection) () =
    async {
        if not tcpConn.Connected then return false
        else
        let message = outputer.ReadLine(true)
        try 
            match message with
            | "exit" -> do! tcpConn.Send "exit" |> Async.Ignore
                        return false
            | _      -> if message.Trim() <> "" 
                        then do! message.Trim() |> tcpConn.Send |> Async.Ignore
                        outputer.WriteLine("me: " + message)
                        return true
        with
        | e -> outputer.WriteLine("log: " + e.Message)
               return false
    }

let recieveUI (outputer:#IOutput) (tcpConn: #IConnection) () =
    async {
        if not tcpConn.Connected then return false
        else
        try
            let! response = tcpConn.Recieve()
            match response with
            | "exit" -> return false
            | _ -> outputer.WriteLine("other: " + response)
                   return true
        with
        | e -> outputer.WriteLine("error: " + e.Message)
               return false
    }

let rec loop (cancel:CancellationTokenSource) f =
    async {
        match! f() with
        | false -> cancel.Cancel(true)
        | true -> do! loop cancel f
    }

let messaging recieve send (outputer: #IOutput) (tcpConn:#IConnection) =
    printfn "write: exit to exit"
    use cancelSrc = new CancellationTokenSource()
    let task =
        [ recieve outputer tcpConn
          send    outputer tcpConn ]
        |> List.map (loop cancelSrc)
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.Ignore
    try
        Async.RunSynchronously (computation=task, cancellationToken=cancelSrc.Token)
    with
    | :? OperationCanceledException ->
        tcpConn.Close()

let exampleReceive = 
    { new IConnection with
          member this.Connected = true
          member this.Recieve() = async { do! Async.Sleep 1000
                                          return "exit" }
          member this.Send(arg1) = async { return true }
          member this.Close() = ()
    }

let exampleOutputer =
    { new IOutput with
          member this.ClearLine() = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
          member this.ReadLine(erase) = Console.ReadLine()
          member this.WriteLine(arg) = Console.WriteLine(arg) }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    messaging recieveUI sendUI exampleOutputer exampleReceive
    0
```

(I wrapped the console with an object so i wont get weird things on screen: outputer)

When I get "exit" over the wire i return false and so the loop calls cancel so it should also stop the sending messages async computation.

However, when I do this, the sendUI gets stuck:

```
async {
    //do stuff
    let message = Console.ReadLine() //BLOCKS! doesn't cancel
    //do stuff
}
```

One fix would be to somehow make Console.ReadLine() an async, however the simple async { return ...}  does not work.

I also tried running it as a task and calling Async.AwaitTask, but this does not work either!

I read that one can use Async.FromContinuations but I couldn't figure out how to use it (and what I tried didn't solve it...)

Little help?

**EDIT**

The reason this doesn't simply work is because the way async computations cancellation work. They check whether to cancel when it reaches a let!/do!/return! etc, and so the solutions above do not work.

**EDIT 2**

Added runnable code sample

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `Console.ReadLine` in its own `async`, then call that with `Async.RunSynchronously` and a `CancellationToken`.  This will allow you to cancel that blocking operation, because it won't be on the same thread as the console itself.

```
open System
open System.Threading

type ITcpConnection =
    abstract member Send: string -> unit

let readLineAsync cancellation =
    async {
        try
            return Some <| Async.RunSynchronously(async { return Console.ReadLine() }, cancellationToken = cancellation)
        with | _ ->
            return None
    }

let receiveUI cancellation (tcpConnection: ITcpConnection) =
    let rec loop () =
        async {
            let! message = readLineAsync cancellation
            match message with
            | Some msg -> msg |> tcpConnection.Send
            | None -> printfn "Chat Session Ended"
            return! loop ()
        }
    loop () |> Async.Start
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. The reason is still the same - the cancellation only works when you reach a let!/do!/return! etc, if you run an async computation and don't use a ! it will never hit a point in which it checks whether it needs to cancel

Comment: @tjw Can you post a complete, runnable example?  I tried this myself in an interactive session, and it worked.